# Getting a matrix from a file in C

Tags: c, matrix

Okay so my assignment is to create a program which reads an unknown nxn matrix from a file and then calculates it's determinant in a certain way. I'm pretty much done except the numbers seem to be jumbling up after getting them from the file.

It's probably easier if you just look at my code, this is the portion up until just after reading the matrix, the values as I said are all jumbled up. It's not the i <= dim because dim counts from 0 so it should run the correct number of times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
FILE       *input;
int     i, j, temp; 
int        dim=0;
double     det;
const char inp_fn[]="matrix.dat";

/*Open File*/
input = fopen(inp_fn, "r");

/*Find the number of lines and hence dimensions*/
while (EOF != (temp = fgetc(input)))
{
    if (temp=='\n')
    {
    ++dim;
    }
}

/*Reset pointer to beginning of file and float the matrix*/
fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);
float      matrix[dim][dim];

/*Check file isn't NULL, if good fill the matrix with the values from the file*/
if( (input != (FILE*) NULL) )
{
    for(i=0; i<=dim; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=dim; j++)
        {
            fscanf(input, "%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
}
else
    {
    printf("Could not open file!\n");
    }
```

So yer if you guys can see anything please tell me, I'm really new to this so i'm probably missing something obvious, thanks.

Comment: Does your file has '\n' after the last line?

Comment: Also, that most probably doesn't cause your error, but the check `input != (FILE*) NULL` should be performed before the first loop which counts number of lines.

Comment: You run out of bounds in your loops, use '<' instead of '<='.

Comment: I haven't run out of bounds that's not it I've already tested that, just tried the input thing and that hasn't changed anything. I know the error is occurring at this point though.

Comment: if it is not a massive big file it is probably a better idea to read in the whole file into a buffer, then from there figure out your dimensions etc. you should avoid file handling if possible.

Comment: I was even surprised that it really compiles. The variable dim is set at run-time but where does `matrix[dim][dim]` go? Since you have variable matrix dimensions shouldn't `matrix` go onto the heap? Then you would have to `malloc`. But, maybe I really can learn something at this point!

Comment: **In C++ you have what's called a `vector` and you can have a vector of vectors and properly deal with this kind of mess.** And you rely on proper input which you never should. I'd lower your grade just for hardcoding it *(as in assuming the number of lines (`height`) is equal to the `width` of the matrix)*. You need to load dynamically each row of numbers and at the end make sure all rows have equal width. Also mind the trailing CRLF, it can play tricks on your current code.

Comment: I understand this isn't the best way to do it, we are using C not C++ so I can't use vectors, also the class we have on learning `malloc` etc is after the assignment is due in so we are not supposed to use it in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loops do not match dimensions of the array.

Either your file doesn't have '\n' after the last line, and then you have matrix of `(dim+1)*(dim+1)` and should define it as `float matrix[dim+1][dim+1]`, or the file has '\n' after the last line, and then you should use `i < dim` and `j < dim` in loops.